# Solr 4.0 UI issue

Tags: pdf, solr, binary, indexing

I just discovered today that there is a new solr release (4.0 ALPHA). So, I give it a try. After setting it up (under Tomcat) I had the following error message: 
This interface requires that you activate the admin request handlers, add the following configuration to your solrconfig.xml:

```
<!-- Admin Handlers - This will register all the standard admin RequestHandlers. -->
<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
```

The above error popped up when I added the following in the solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
   </requestHandler>
```

Does anybody know what it is wrong?

Thank you in advance,

Tom
Greece

**The solr folder structure:**

```
+solr
   +conf
   +data
   +lib
      -contrib
      -dist
```

**The solr.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
    <core name="collection1" instanceDir="." />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

**The solrconfig.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_40</luceneMatchVersion>

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/extraction/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
  <!--<lib dir="lib/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />-->

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/velocity/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-extras-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/contrib/extraction/lib/" regex="tika-core-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/extraction/lib/" regex="tika-parsers-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="/total/crap/dir/ignored" /> 

  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>

  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" 
                    class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.StandardDirectoryFactory}"/>

  <indexConfig>

  </indexConfig>
  <jmx />

  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">

     <autoCommit> 
       <maxTime>15000</maxTime> 
       <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
     </autoCommit>

    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.data.dir:}</str>
    </updateLog>


  </updateHandler>

  <query>

    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>

    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>

    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                     size="512"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="0"/>

    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>

    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>

   <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>

   <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>

    <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">

      </arr>
    </listener>
    <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <lst>
          <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </listener>

    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>

    <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>

  </query>

  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" >

    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" 
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000" />

    <httpCaching never304="true" />

  </requestDispatcher>

  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
   </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>

    </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/get" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="omitHeader">true</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

       <!-- VelocityResponseWriter settings -->
       <str name="wt">velocity</str>
       <str name="v.template">browse</str>
       <str name="v.layout">layout</str>
       <str name="title">Solritas</str>

       <!-- Query settings -->
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">
          text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>
       <str name="mm">100%</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>

       <str name="mlt.qf">
         text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>
       <str name="mlt.fl">text,features,name,sku,id,manu,cat</str>
       <int name="mlt.count">3</int>

       <!-- Faceting defaults -->
       <str name="facet">on</str>
       <str name="facet.field">cat</str>
       <str name="facet.field">manu_exact</str>
       <str name="facet.query">ipod</str>
       <str name="facet.query">GB</str>
       <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
       <str name="facet.pivot">cat,inStock</str>
       <str name="facet.range.other">after</str>
       <str name="facet.range">price</str>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.end">600</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.gap">50</int>
       <str name="facet.range">popularity</str>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.end">10</int>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.gap">3</int>
       <str name="facet.range">manufacturedate_dt</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.start">NOW/YEAR-10YEARS</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.end">NOW</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.gap">+1YEAR</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">before</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">after</str>

       <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
       <str name="hl">on</str>
       <str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>

       <!-- Spell checking defaults -->
       <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>       
       <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
       <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>           
     </lst>

     <!-- append spellchecking to our list of components -->
     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">

  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- All the main content goes into "text"... if you need to return
           the extracted text or do highlighting, use a stored field. -->
      <str name="fmap.content">text</str>
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />

  <requestHandler name="/analysis/document" 
                  class="solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" />

  <requestHandler name="/admin/" 
                  class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />

  <!-- ping/healthcheck -->
  <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Echo the request contents back to the client -->
  <requestHandler name="/debug/dump" class="solr.DumpRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
     <str name="echoHandler">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

    <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" startup="lazy" /> 

  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
    <!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
      -->
    </lst>

    <!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">true</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
    </lst>

  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>

      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>

  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="clustering"
                   enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                   class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >
    <!-- Declare an engine -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <!-- The name, only one can be named "default" -->
      <str name="name">default</str>

      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm</str>

      <str name="LingoClusteringAlgorithm.desiredClusterCountBase">20</str>

      <str name="carrot.lexicalResourcesDir">clustering/carrot2</str>

      <str name="MultilingualClustering.defaultLanguage">ENGLISH</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">stc</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/clustering"
                  startup="lazy"
                  enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                  class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
      <str name="clustering.engine">default</str>
      <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>
      <!-- The title field -->
      <str name="carrot.title">name</str>
      <str name="carrot.url">id</str>
      <!-- The field to cluster on -->
       <str name="carrot.snippet">features</str>
       <!-- produce summaries -->
       <bool name="carrot.produceSummary">true</bool>
       <!-- the maximum number of labels per cluster -->
       <!--<int name="carrot.numDescriptions">5</int>-->
       <!-- produce sub clusters -->
       <bool name="carrot.outputSubClusters">false</bool>

       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">
         text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    </lst>     
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>clustering</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the terms component -->
  <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
     <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="terms">true</bool>
    </lst>     
    <arr name="components">
      <str>terms</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the elevator component -->
  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap" 
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <fragmenter name="regex" 
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html" 
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>

      <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
      <encoder name="html" 
               class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="weighted" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default" 
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <!-- 
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.multiValuedSeparatorChar">/</str>
        </lst>
        -->
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored" 
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <boundaryScanner name="default" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>

      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator" 
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
          <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>

  <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">

    <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>

    <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter" startup="lazy"/>

  <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
  </queryResponseWriter>

  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the log file and i guess the error lies here/ **Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr.\conf/** It is not able to locate the solrconfig.xml file. 
Apology,i dont know how to rectify it. May be a pro can . Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused most likely by some other error in your config. To find out what is going on go to Tomcat folder /logs/ and look for a file catalina.*.log

Reading through exception message you should be able to figure out witch part of configuration fails, if not paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar a problem when trying to deploy as a webapp under tomcat. I found this tutorial http://adeithzya.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/using-apache-solr-with-spring-framework/ and was able to get admin UI to work with one minor change, ie instead of windows file structure i was using Mac OS.

"I will be using Apache Tomcat as the web server for SOLR, hence browse to Tomcat configuration directory, in my case  it’s “C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\conf\Catalina\localhost” add new .xml file “my-solr-app.xml” (it can be any name). Here are the content of the .xml file:

Start Apache Tomcat and open a browser to the “http://localhost:8080/my-solr-app/”, you may need to change the port number configured for Tomcat web server. If you see the welcome screen, then you’ve just finished Apache SOLR setup."

I had a small hiccup because i did not copy the correct folder, ensure you copy the entire "example" directory in your new directory

Answer (score 0):

In solr ALPHA 4.0 distribution there is example folders. go to example-->solr--config folder
and copy the solrconfig.xml to your core whatever you have created . and if you r using data import handler copy this in solrconfig.xml

    
        data-config.xml

your problem will be solved i have already tried and succeded

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. To fix it first make sure tomcat knows where your solr home is.

you can either set the path to solr home in the webapps/solr/web.xml file

```
<env-entry>
 <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
 <env-entry-value>/Path/To/My/solr/Home/solr/</env-entry-value>
 <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
```

Or you can do this export JAVA_OPTS=”$JAVA_OPTS -Dsolr.solr.home=/my/custom/solr/home/dir/”

I also upgraded to tomcat 7.0.8 because there's a url bug in earlier versions of tomcat 7 that prevent solr from working.